# Выдает ошибку функция fopen HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, telegram-bot

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['user_name'];

$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];

$email = $_POST['user_email'];

$token = "1516441406:AAEi30721lyOLlc7bKgni-FWJDGzPrAPP0o";

$chat_id = "-592602248";

$txt = "";

$arr = array(
  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Email' => $email
);


foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};


$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");


if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: thank-you.html');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема здесь в том, что вам нужно кодировать кириллические символы в объекты URL. Попробуйте использовать `rawurlencode` для `$txt`: `$txt = rawurlencode($txt)`.

Оригинал ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63667704/4772782